# Worm-Crawling Motion in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, infinite-loop

I am trying to work out an efficient method of performing the following behavior in OpenGL.

I am animating a worm-like fellow (basically I want a rectangle with a visible eye of some sort - nothing complicated) that should move by expanding to twice its length at the front, and retracting to its original size from the back. The worm will reverse direction when it reaches the window edge.

I am having major difficulty in getting the motion correct, and somewhat minor difficulty positioning the eye. If I simply draw two polygons one after the other with their relative positions, can I expect the latter to be painted over the former? My motion at the moment presents an infinite loop which I am having trouble altering to another method conceptually. I cannot figure out the loop structure to have the doubling/contracting motion and approach termination efficiently.

Current code below:

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

float wormX = 0;
float wormY = 0;
float wormWidth = 100;
float wormHeight = 75;
bool wormCrawl = true;

void timer( int value )
{
const int w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
if( wormX + wormWidth >= w / 2 ) //If worm hits edge, reverse direction!
{
    wormX = 2;
}

while( wormCrawl )
{
    wormX += 2; //Move the worm
    wormWidth = 2*wormWidth; //Extend the front
    wormWidth = (1/2)*wormWidth; //Retract the back

}

glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

const int w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
const int h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( -w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

const float leftCorner = wormX;
const float rightCorner = leftCorner + wormWidth;
const float bottomCorner = wormY;
const float topCorner = bottomCorner + wormHeight;
//Worm
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner, topCorner);
    glVertex2d(rightCorner, topCorner);
    glVertex2d(rightCorner, bottomCorner);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner, bottomCorner);
glEnd();
//Worm eye
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner, topCorner);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner + 10, topCorner);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner + 10, bottomCorner);
    glVertex2d(leftCorner, bottomCorner);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutCreateWindow ("Inchworm Crawl");

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 That's only true if you're using a depth buffer, which the code in the question isn't doing.

Comment: @duskwuff Then that's its' own problem :<

Comment: Do you think it is advisable, then, to use a depth buffer in this case, or is there an alternative? I am not the most familiar with using depth buffer implementation, though I'll take a look at the docs.

Comment: You don't need a depth buffer just for doing simple 2d drawing. For the animation you need to use a time step to break down the phases of the animation. Right now your loop both expands and contracts the width in the same iteration so you are not going to see this animated since no drawing occurs in this loop. Instead in your timer function depending on whether you are in the expand or contract phase you should either increase or decrease the width. No loop is needed because your timer function will be called again after drawing.

Comment: Makes sense. Where should I make the change between expanding and contracting, though? I assume after a draw operation, perhaps after the redisplay is posted?

Answer (score 1):

so first off, we want to make life much easier, you should try abstracting your worm to a class. I'm assuming you probably want to carry on developing on this afterwards but in any case its still good practise. This will also make our draw calls much easier.

Okay, so assuming we now have our `Worm` class that class will have its own draw function, we want to try to keep our draw calls in the `display()` function in our main as simple as possible. Imagine what you would have to do if you wanted to draw another worm.

so in your worm class your `draw()` method will look something like this:

```
void Worm::draw()
{
    const float leftCorner = wormX;
    const float rightCorner = leftCorner + wormWidth;
    const float bottomCorner = wormY;
    const float topCorner = bottomCorner + wormHeight;
    //Worm
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner, topCorner);
        glVertex2d(rightCorner, topCorner);
        glVertex2d(rightCorner, bottomCorner);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner, bottomCorner);
    glEnd();
    //Worm eye
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner, topCorner);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner + 10, topCorner);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner + 10, bottomCorner);
        glVertex2d(leftCorner, bottomCorner);
    glEnd();
}
```

Okay so that's just the basics of it, but I still haven't answered your actual question. I'm not sure which version of freeglut you are using, but hopefully you have the latest. In general if you are planning on doing more than just rendering, you should try to stay away from `glutmainloop();`. It basically stops you from being able to do any logic outside of your render loop, which effectively means everything in your program is going to be locked to the frame rate. instead you should look at writing a game loop in your main function which then calls `glutmainloopevent()` each time you want to render a frame.

So now more onto the movement, once you have created your game loop, logically you can put all of your update functionality in here, and at the end of the loop, you can call `glutmainloopevent()` note that this loop will also be a semi-infinite loop. It will run while some flag is true and then you can terminate it once your worm has wriggled around enough. :P

So now to our worm class we can add some more functionality for moving our worm and increasing his width we can call it something like `move()`. And also to simplify things we can add a flag to our worm that tells us if he should be shrinking or growing. This will just be a Boolean that is initialized to false on creation of our worm object.

```
void Worm::move(bool direction)
{
    if(growing)
    {
        wormWidth += 1;
        if(wormWidth > thresholdWidth)
        {
            growing = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wormWidth += 1;
        if(wormWidth > thresholdWidth)
        {
            growing = false;
        }
    }
    if(direction)
    {
        wormx += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wormx -= 1;
    }
}
```

Now I haven't tested this could, but I would imagine that it should do something close to what you are looking for. I don't currently have glut setup on my work pc nor openGL for that matter. But if this doesn't do exactly what you are looking for, just drop me some comments I can take a look when I get home from work.

One last thing to note, you will call your move function in your game loop as well, for now for your game loop you can probably just have a while loop doing this, but eventually you  can set it to only update X amount of times per second and draw Y amount of times per second.

One thing to note is that because you aren't drawing more than one thing per frame its not going to make a difference. You can just keep drawing your worm, that's what the `gLClear()` function is doing for you, it is clearing everything currently in the color buffer, if you were busy with an application that explicitly used 3D you would need to add the depth buffer as well, otherwise things wouldn't be drawn in the correct order and you might get z-fighting or some things being draw over by things that are actually behind them.

Hope I didn't get to tangential and that this post can be of some value to you!

Goodluck!

Comment: If you need an example of what your game loop/main loop will look like I can edit my post and add that.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer! It's not quite what I was looking for, but it gave me some idea. However, I am still stuck a little.

I want the worm to move like an inchworm. So it should double its width when moving forward, then shrink back to its original size before repeating the motion. I have since figured out the eye drawing though, so that is progress indeed! :)

Comment: I suggest possibly having a number of frames for which the worm would extend say 15 frames, if you draw at 60 frames per second this would mean for 1/4 of a second your worm will expand. So in your characters draw function you can keep track of how many frames you've drawn, using the modulus operator after 60 frames to return to 0. You can then invert your growing/shrinking flag every 15 frames. Knowing that it is expanding for 15 frames, you can calculate the length that it would be at the end of those frames. This is not a very clean solution, but it should get the job done.